# Commands not found: netstat, nmap on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, package-management

I'm using the following CentOS:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

The commands `nmap`, `netstat` and `lsof` are not found on CentOS7. Why?

```
$ type -a nmap
bash: type: nmap: not found

$ type -a netstat
bash: type: netstat: not found

$ type -a lsof   
bash: type: lsof: not found
```

What should I do to make them work?

Answer (score 65):

The package `net-tools` was deprecated in CentOS7 in favour of the `iproute2` suite. You may either install it manually or check out this blogpost for replacement commands:

- http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/

#### EDIT

Here is the URL to Red Hat's Bugzilla for RHEL7 that covers the deprecation of `netstat` in more detail: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1119297

*Excerpt*

> As stated before, net-tools are deprecated thus shouldn't be used
>   unless necessary. Behaviour in RHEL 7 is the same as in Fedora -
>   net-tools is missing from minimal install, but is in @base (~=
>   @standard in Fedora) which is installed in all non-minimal
>   configurations.

There are also other tickets that deal with this such as IDs 682308 and 687920. Note that they are assigned to the Fedora project and are quite old.

Comment: lsof is not listed in your link of substitutions

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you put the substitution of `lsof` directly in your answer

Comment: I don't think that `lsof` was deprecated. It's just not installed by default. You can get it with `yum install lsof`.

Answer (score 35):

just do:

```
yum install net-tools
```

Comment: It only took a few minutes for me to determine that `netstat -plnt` was replaced by `ss -plnt` using [this link](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/) from @DanKeder's answer above.  I think we should first try to make the distribution's recommended solutions work instead of reverting to deprecated approaches.

Answer (score 12):

Whenever you cannot find executables on a Red Hat based distro and you know their names, you should do 1 of the following 2 things.

#### Use repoquery

You can search the YUM repositories that are available to your system by using the command `repoquery`. If it isn't installed, then do a `yum install yum-utils`.

```
$ repoquery -qf */nmap
nmap-2:6.40-4.el7.x86_64
```

From here you can see which packages have an executable with those names. Here's all of them at once.

```
$ repoquery -qf */netstat */lsof */nmap
net-tools-0:2.0-0.17.20131004git.el7.x86_64
ctdb-tests-0:2.5.1-2.el7.x86_64
lsof-0:4.87-4.el7.x86_64
nmap-2:6.40-4.el7.x86_64
ctdb-tests-0:2.5.1-2.el7.x86_64
```

Now just do a `sudo yum install lsof` or `sudo yum install nmap` to install these missing packages.

#### Use yum search

You can also do a similar search using `yum search <executable>`.

```
$ yum search netstat     
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * extras: mirror.cisp.com
 * updates: centos-mirror.jchost.net
================================================================== Matched: netstat ==================================================================
dstat.noarch : Versatile resource statistics tool
net-snmp.x86_64 : A collection of SNMP protocol tools and libraries
net-tools.x86_64 : Basic networking tools
```

With this approach you'll need to do a bit of digging to confirm that the resulting packages include the executable you're looking for. I typically look in there lit of files for what I want, but for that you'll have to use `repoquery`.

```
$ repoquery -ql net-tools.x86_64  | grep netstat
/bin/netstat
/usr/share/man/de/man8/netstat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man8/netstat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/netstat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/pt/man8/netstat.8.gz
```

So using my first approach saves you the extra steps.

#### netstat's deprecation

Apparently in CentOS 7 `netstat`, which is part of the package `net-tools` has been officially deprecated, so you should be using `ss` (part of the package iproute2), going forward.

Comment: +1 for the `repoquery` and `yum search` commands.

Answer (score 5):

Upvoted *slm's* answer, just making it easier to find the info I used. I wanted to do:

```
netstat -nlp | grep httpd
```

Instead, on *CentOS 7* I just did:

```
ss -nlp | grep httpd
```

Which works, didn't even have to install it on *CentOS 7 minimal*.

Do `man ss` for usage details.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you simply don't have these tools installed.  On CentOS, you should be able to install them easily with `yum`.  Try this:

```
$ yum install nmap netstat
```

Comment: Actually, this seems like a fairly valid answer. But, for the record, it does not take much time nor work to get 50 rep; if you really feel something should be posted as a comment, just wait until you can actually post it as one. (it won't take long)

Comment: Also note, `netstat` has been deprecated in favor of `ss`. Doubt it'll go away any time soon, but just fyi. I'd bet that `ss` is installed already.

Comment: @HalosGhost: It may take substantially longer than that, and you have to ask or answer some questions for it as well.

Comment: OP specified CentOS 7. netstat is not a valid package in that distribution.